# Passing a list to Javascript UDF in Apache Pig

Tags: javascript, apache-pig, user-defined-functions

If I have an array of stuff in Pig, like so:

```
datas   = load './data.txt' using PigStorage( '\t');
list    = load './frobdata.txt' using PigStorage();
```

And I want to pass these on to a UDF, like so:

```
register './enfrobinate.js' using javascript as frob;
frobbed = foreach datas generate flatten( frob.enfrobinate( list, $0 ) );
```

I cannot seem to find a prototype that works for passing a list to javascript, and the Pig documentation is not real clear on datatypes for Javascript UDFs.

I am aware of `cross` in Pig. This is not what I need (It gives me a cartesian product. Which is okay, except when we start getting very huge lists. The 'list' in this case is a few thousand items and the datas is many millions of items.)

Comment: To begin with, `list` is not an object that you can access inside a `generate` clause.  You'll have to get a tuple or bag containing all your data and pass that.  I don't know how Javascript will handle the complex data types, though.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but do not know how I would get a bag from `list` here? I have seen suggestions to pass `list` in as json instead. Is there a way to get json easily from `list` here? If so, I think writing it up as an answer would be helpful so that I might 'approve' it :)

Comment: Presumably, this is the same problem as your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841375. If so, see the suggestion there for how to get everything into a bag.